# How to find compression efficiency using Huffman encoding?

Tags: c#, compression, huffman-code

I have compressed a binary file using Huffman encoding. Now I am trying to find the compression efficiency.

In my binary file I have symbols (buch of 0 & 1) and frequency (repetition of symbols).
Suppose I have:

- symbol :0 freq : 173
- symbol :1 freq : 50
- symbol :2 freq : 48
- symbol :3 freq : 45

Currently every symbol is encoded in UInt64, so size of file would be (173+50+48+45)*8=2528 bytes if my way of calculating the size is correct. Please correct me if I am wrong. On debugging I get 2536, 8 more I don't know why?

After compression I got encoding like this

- symbol : 0 Code : 1
- symbol : 1 Code : 00
- symbol : 2 Code : 011
- symbol : 3 Code : 010

Could some one please tell me how to get Huffman compression of this binary file using these information? I tried searching on Google but there is no sample of binary file they have some frequency of float type which I am not able to understand how to relate them with my Binary file.

Comment: An example of Huffman implementation in C++ if it helps (including doc): https://github.com/barakman/Huffman

Answer (score 1):

You need to simply compute how many total bits you end up with:

```
173 * 1 + 50 * 2 + 48 * 3 + 45 * 3
```

That comes to 552 bits. Converting to whole bytes gives us 69 bytes. So that's a compression to 69/2528 or about 3% of the original, assuming the de-compressor can know the dictionary and so on. Also assuming your input symbols (0 to 3) are 64-bit values, for some reason.

Comment: could you please give me small algo for how to count the these "1" , "2" and "3" from encoding ?

Comment: @unwind You're wrongly comparing bits to bytes, 69 bytes to 2528 bits. Comparing 552 bits to 2528 bits we get a compression to ~22%. If the dictionary has to be stored as well, he is probably better off just using 2-bit encoding.

Comment: @user234839 He is calculating the symbol frequency times the length of the code. Symbol 2 (011) has 3 bits, as does Symbol 3, S1 has two bits, S1 only one.

Comment: @Mathias 2528 is not Bits its Bytes (Binary file is big)it's in 2828 bytes. I am bit confused now , But i am sure size is in Bytes because when i debug it then my variable which stores the file is byte[] fileContents type. and it gives 2528 on debugging

Comment: @unwind could you please clear this confusion with what is right or wrong ?

Comment: @user234839 How does your file look exactly? If its 2828 bytes, then each symbol is represented by 64 bits. Are your symbols represented as long ints?

Comment: @unwind what? He has 173+50+48+45=316 symbols, therefore 316 bytes if each symbol is represented by one byte like you assumed.

Comment: @Mathias Much confusion, I'm sorry. I can't do math. It seems the symbol size is 8 bytes, for some reason I cannot understand (316 * 8 == 2528).

Comment: @Mathias My data type is "UInt64" and i store the file contents in byte[] array_File_Contents ;

Comment: @user234839 Well then the easiest data compression would be to cast it to uint8, "compressing" it to 12.5%. If you stuffed 4 symbols into one byte, it would be "compressed" to 3.125% and your dictionary would be at most 32 bytes long. The Huffman coding compresses to 2.73%, so compared to a simple code book approach you save another 12% but loose simple accessibility without decompression. Of course, if you have more (or sometimes less) symbols Huffman is still the way to go.

Comment: @Mathias do we have uint8 in c# ?  (I a new to c#) i know that uint16(short), uint32(int) and uint64(long) but don't know uint8. Does it exist in c# ?

Comment: This question was about C#? I don't know C#. but Google finds [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bdb6693.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Based on provided frequencies the tree is wrong. It must be `0 10 110 111` It always ends on with all positive bits. Solutions, which are different than Huffman trees, may work but do not provide best compression.